# Excel 365 on Mac with Background image set shows gridlines as white, ignores set preferences

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I'm setting up Excel 365 on my Mac and want the spreadsheet itself to show as dark in addition to the app. I set the background to a black image and the sheet shows with a black background; perfect.

The gridlines show up as white though. No matter what I set them to in Excel > Preferences > View > Gridlines (color), the gridlines always show as white. I want them a dark grey. I tried blue and red just as tests. They're always white when the background is set.

Notes:

- Looking to set gridline color; not borders.
- Background set in page setup; no cell fill.

Is there a setting or something I'm overlooking?

Excel for Mac v16.64

[image]

Comment: I changed the gridlines to blue on my Mac. But it only changed after clicking on the red exit dot in the upper left corner of the view menu (see your screenshot).

Comment: By default Excel didn't have Gridlines for Worksheet, you should add the Border for cells, you can try to test this method.

Comment: @Lee thanks for the suggestion, but borders and gridlines are not the same. Gridlines only show up in the UI as a visual guide. Borders are included when printed and can easily get changed/missed when inserting/copying/pasting cells.